# Comparing data.frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames

```
> a1
v1  v2  v3
ABCA1   --> GIF
ACTA1   --| CSNK2A1
ACTN4   --| HDAC7
ACTN4   --> RARA

> a2
v1  v2  v3
ABCA1   --| GIF
ACTA1   --| CSNK2A1
ABCD2   --| HDAC7
ACTN4   --> XYZ1
```

I want output where `a1$v1 == a2$v1` && `a1$v3 == a2$v3` && `a1$v2 != a2$v2`. So, the outcome will be:

```
> a3
ABCA1   --> GIF
```

Because Row 1 fulfill all those conditions. In row 2 `condition 3` is not fulfilled. In row 3 `condition 1` is not fulfilled and in row 4 `condition 2` is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are comparing the 'v1' column in 'a1' and 'a2' datasets, and use `&` instead of `&&`, we get the expected output

```
a1[(a1$v1==a2$v1) & (a1$v3==a2$v3) & (a1$v2 != a2$v2), , drop=FALSE]
#    v1  v2  v3
#1 ABCA1 --> GIF
```

According to the description from `?"&&"`

> ‘&’ and ‘&&’ indicate logical AND and ‘|’ and ‘||’ indicate
>        logical OR.  The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in
>        much the same way as arithmetic operators.  The longer form
>        evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each
>        vector.

#### Update

If we need to compare one row in 'a1' against all the rows, we can `paste` the rows in each datasets using `do.call(paste,..`, and loop through `lapply` on the `paste` elements of 'a1' and compare against the `paste`d 'a2' or this can be done using `outer`.

```
 lapply(do.call(paste, a1), '==', do.call(paste, a2))
```

Or

```
 outer(do.call(paste, a1), do.call(paste, a2), '==')
```

#### data

```
a1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("ABCA1", "ACTA1", "ACTN4", "ACTN4"),
 v2 = c("-->", 
"--|", "--|", "-->"), v3 = c("GIF", "CSNK2A1", "HDAC7", "RARA"
)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))

a2 <- structure(list(v1 = c("ABCA1", "ACTA1", "ABCD2", "ACTN4"), 
v2 = c("--|", 
"--|", "--|", "-->"), v3 = c("GIF", "CSNK2A1", "HDAC7", "XYZ1"
)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: @user3253470  It gave the expected output as you showed based on the input datasets.

Comment: @user3253470  Check whether the columns have leading/lagging spaces.  In that case `==` may return `FALSE`, ie. `"-->" == " -->"
#[1] FALSE`

Comment: @user3253470 If you have that cases, `library(stringr); a1[] <- lapply(a1, str_trim); a2[] <- lapply(a2, str_trim)` and then proceed as before.

Comment: Thanks it's done, I don't have enough score to upvote the answer..!

Comment: There is a little problem. I want to compare if "any"  `a1$v1 == a2$v1` & `a1$v3` == `a2$v3` & `a1$v2 != a2$v2`. This code is making a comparison of every particular row (for example Row1 of `a1` vs Row 1 of `a2`). Can you help me on this ? @akrun

Comment: I think my comment is confusing. In other words, take 1 row from `a1` and compare it against all rows of `a2` for fulfilling the above condition. Not just a comparison of Row 1 from `a1` to Row1 from `a2` and Row 2 from `a1` to Row 2 from `a2`and so on..

Comment: Try `lapply(do.call(paste, a1), '==', do.call(paste, a2))` or `outer(do.call(paste, a1), do.call(paste, a2), '==')`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you  again. I think I am still not clear. `ABCA1` is `a1$V1`, `-->` is `a1$V2` and `GIF` is `a1$V3`, overall this comprises Row 1 of `a1`. Now apply above condition (`a1[(a1$v1==a2$v1) & (a1$v3==a2$v3) & (a1$v2 != a2$v2), , drop=FALSE]`) for row 1 of `a1` vs. every row of `a2`. Where all 3 conditions meet, print only those lines.

Comment: @user3253470 You mentioned to compare the rows of one against the other.  Sorry.

Comment: The previous code was comparing row wise. it worked in case of example because there the rows which were fulfilling the conditions were ranked the same. (e.g. row 1 of a1 vs. row 1 of a2). If I disturb the row orders then that code doesn't work.

Comment: @user3253470 Based on the example, wouldn't it be all `FALSE` after comparing.

Comment: Yes you're right. Instead of giving hard coded position e.g `a1$V1` it should be something else. Just re rank the data.frame a2, replace the row 1 with row 3 and vice versa. Now I want the same result as with old `ABCA1   --> GIF`.

Comment: @user3253470  If you want the same result as before, why you are doing this way?

Comment: After this re-ranking. the row 1 of a1 and row 3rd of a2 will be fulfilling the matching condition and should be printed as result. As my dataset is quite big so there should be a general approach for matching. Any row vs. any row comparison, where 1st and 3rd element of those rows are same and 2nd element is not same.

Comment: @user3253470 If you are comparing any rows, then use `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: In actual my a1 comprise of 2919 rows and a2 comprise of 3623 rows. I want every row in both data.frames where element 1 and 3 are identical (`(a1$element1==a2$element1) & (a1$element3==a2$element3)`) while element 2 are not identical (`(a1$element2 != a2$element2)`)

Comment: @user3253470 I guess this should be a separate question as the original question was different.

Comment: And what I should use against `!=` ??

Comment: @user3253470 You can do `!a1$element2 %in% a2$element2`

Comment: How to represent `element` ?? I have posted the new question, perhaps you can help me there [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973838/comparing-elements-of-data-frames-in-r)

Comment: @user3253470 I think you need to create a separate example where this solution won't give the same output as you desired so that it becomes less confusing.

Comment: [Here is the new question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973838/comparing-elements-of-data-frames-in-r)

Comment: @user3253470  Glad to know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91716/discussion-between-user3253470-and-akrun).

Comment: can you help me with this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420909/compare-matrices-to-find-the-differences]