# Comparing elements of data.frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames

```
> a1
v1  v2  v3
ABCA1   --> GIF
ACTA1   --| CSNK2A1
ACTN4   --| HDAC7
ACTN4   --> RARA

> a2
v1  v2  v3
ACTA1   --| CSNK2A1
ABCD2   --| HDAC7
ABCA1   --| GIF
ACTN4   --> XYZ1
```

I want output where `a1$element1 == a2$element1` & `a1$element3 == a2$element3` & `a1$element2 != a2$element2`. So, the outcome will be:

```
> a3
ABCA1   --> GIF
```

As all elements in this row fulfills our all 3 conditions. It is row 1 in `a1` and row 3 in `a2`. As you can see (row 1 of `a1` and row 3 of `a2`) `ABCA1 == ABCA1` & `--> != --|` & `GIF == GIF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `merge`:

```
m2 <- merge(a1, a2, by=c("v1", "v3"))
m2[m2[,3] != m2[,4],][c(1,3,2)]
#     v1 v2.x  v3
#1 ABCA1  --> GIF
```

We first merge on columns 1 and 3. That will connect the cases of the first two conditions. For the last condition, test for the cases where the column symbols are different.

Also `stringsAsFactors` should be set to FALSE when creating the data frames.

---

With `data.table`, you can merge using its shallow copying efficiency.

```
setDT(a1)[a2, on = c("v1", "v3")][v2 != i.v2]
      v1  v2  v3 i.v2
1: ABCA1 --> GIF  --|
```

Comment: Thanks.. It did the job.

Comment: Maybe also `library(data.table) ; setDT(a1)[a2, on = c("v1", "v3"), nomatch = 0L][v2 != i.v2]` just for fun

Comment: @DavidArenburg Can you help me with this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484595/data-frame-merge-and-selection-of-values-which-are-common-in-2-data-frames]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
a1[ intersect(which((paste0(a1$v1, a1$v3) %in% paste0(a2$v1, a2$v3))),
              which(a1$v2 != a2$v2)) ,]

#     v1  v2  v3
#1 ABCA1 --> GIF
```

First, find which rows in a1 and a2 have common columns 1 and 3. Then find which rows do not have the second column in common. Then get the intersect of the two and use this to subset `a1`.

Data:

```
a1 <- read.table(header=T,text='v1  v2  v3
ABCA1   --> GIF
ACTA1   --| CSNK2A1
ACTN4   --| HDAC7
ACTN4   --> RARA', stringsAsFactors=F)

a2 <- read.table(header=T,text='v1  v2  v3
ACTA1   --| CSNK2A1
ABCD2   --| HDAC7
ABCA1   --| GIF
ACTN4   --> XYZ1', stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Can you help me with this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484595/data-frame-merge-and-selection-of-values-which-are-common-in-2-data-frames]